# Is $\beta$ sometimes Bessel-corrected?

Tags: regression, finance

I was reading about $\beta$ in finance, and I found the formula  pictured below on [this website](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/knowledge/finance/beta-coefficient/).  Is the n-1 a typo or do some people actually define $\beta$ with a Bessel correction?    [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula is correct.

The general unbiased estimator for the variance-covariance matrix is with the Bessel correction.

When the data is known to be normally distributed, the MLE is with the $n$ at the denominator.

It seems that $R_m$ is assumed to be Normal, while $(R_e, R_m)$ clearly is not a bivariate Normal random variable (so the Bessel correction applies).

You can find a derivation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_of_covariance_matrices#Maximum-likelihood_estimation_for_the_multivariate_normal_distribution

Beta can be defined in three equivalent ways:

1. OLS estimate $\hat{\beta}_1$ for the slope of the linear regression $$
   y_i=\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \epsilon_i, \quad i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, N\}
   $$
2. using the expression $\frac{\text{cov}[X,Y]}{\text{var}[X]}$. This is equivalent to (1) for OLS.
   The least squared estimate for $\beta_1$ is

$$
\hat{\beta}_1=\frac{\sum_i x_i y_i - \frac{1}{N}\sum_i x_i \sum_j y_j}{\sum_i x_i^2-\frac{1}{N} \left(\sum_i x_i\right)^2} = \frac{\text{cov}[X,Y]}{\text{var}[X]}
$$

3. Using the Pearson's correlation $\rho=\frac{\text{cov}[X,Y]}{\sqrt{\text{var}[X]\text{var}[Y]}}$

$$
\hat{\beta}_1=\frac{\text{cov}[X,Y]}{\text{var}[X]}=\rho\frac{\sqrt{\text{var}[Y]}}{\sqrt{\text{var}[X]}}
$$

Comment: so the top is the unbiased estimator for the covariance and the bottom is an ML estimator for the variance of one of the variables.  But why take the quotient? What does that represent? Also do you know for sure this (with n-1) is what finance people mean by $beta$?  I thought beta was just supposed to be the result of a 1 dimensional regression which seems like it shouldn’t have the n-1

Comment: “an* unbiased” & “the* MLE”

Comment: @Timkinsella yes, the beta formula is correct. There are 3 ways to define beta, one is this one, the other is the coefficient of the linear regression and the third one is based on the correlation https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/beta-formula/

Comment: ah so three *nonequivalent* definitions?

Comment: Do you have any sense of which is most common? I’ve often read references to beta without an accompanying formula or definition

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. The three formulations are identical. The OLS regression slope is identical to the covariance-variance ratio https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Simple_linear_regression_model, and the latter can be written in terms of Pearson's correlations https://en.wiykipedia.org/wiki/Beta_(finance)

Comment: I've edited the answer to clarify the possible misunderstandings.

Comment: Sorry what is OLS?

Comment: OLS=ordinary least-squares https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares It's the method that minimizes the squares of the differences between the observed and predicted dependent variables https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Matrix/vector_formulation

Comment: should one of the  $\sum_i x_i$ in the numerator of (2) be  $\sum_i y_i$?

Comment: Yes sorry for the typo.

Comment: so youre saying that numerator is the same as $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_i \big((x_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_j x_j)(y_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_j y_j)\big)$? sorry if i'm being dumb and just need to write it out

Comment: Don’t worry we are all learning. The formulas I’ve written don’t take into account of the bias. You just need to change the denominator with the Bessel correction for the covariance and $n$ for the variances.

Comment: you can find the details here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Fitting_the_regression_line The Bessel correction is necessary for small datasets. The OLS solution is given by the covariance-variance ratio where the _estimated_ values require the Bessel correction (not if the variance-covariance is estimated from a multivariate Normal random variable).

Comment: ok thanks again for your help